# Convert Bit field table to table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table showing locations with a BIT column for each tool in use at each location:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[ToolsSelected] (
    [LocationID] NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    [Tool1] INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    [Tool2] INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    [Tool3] INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    [Tool4] INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([LocationID])
);

LocID  Tool1  Tool2  Tool3  Tool4
-----  -----  -----  -----  -----
AZ     0      1      1      0
NY     1      0      1      1
```

I need to convert this to a table by LocationID indicating which tools at which locations:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[ByLocation] (
    [LocationID] NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    [Tool] NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,  -- Column title of ToolsSelected table
    PRIMARY KEY ([LocationID],  [Tool])
);

LocID  Tool
-----  -----
AZ     Tool2
AZ     Tool3
NY     Tool1
NY     Tool3
NY     Tool4
```

The idea is that each location can select the tools they need, I then need to query the tools table to get details (versions, etc) for each tool selected. Each location is unique; each tool is unique. Is there a way to do this or a much better implementation?

Comment: Do you need to move the data once, permanently, to another table? Or do you think you need to move the data to another table in order to run a query to get the results you're after? Are you planning to run this conversion every time you run the query, or once a day, or how do you plan to keep the two tables in sync? Typically it's not wise to duplicate information.

Comment: This will be run periodically as additonal locations are added which could be daily in the near term.  The plan was to move the data to another table in order to run a query to get the results. I was planning to run this conversion every time the query is run to get the latest data.

Comment: If you can run a query that generates the desired output to stuff into another table, why not just run that query directly against the existing table and avoid the other table? This is the redundancy I'm talking about - what you think you want to do is similar to borrowing $50 from John to pay John the $50 you owe him. You're inventing a middle man for no purpose.

Comment: Ok, how do I run a query which returns the column names and whether the data is true.  If you could provide an example I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer to the immediate question, given only 4 tools columns:

```
SELECT LocID = LocationID, Tool
FROM
(
    SELECT LocationID, Tool = 'Tool1' FROM dbo.ToolsSelected WHERE Tool1 = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LocationID, Tool = 'Tool2' FROM dbo.ToolsSelected WHERE Tool2 = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LocationID, Tool = 'Tool3' FROM dbo.ToolsSelected WHERE Tool3 = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LocationID, Tool = 'Tool4' FROM dbo.ToolsSelected WHERE Tool4 = 1
) AS x
ORDER BY LocID, Tool;
```

With 40 columns, you could do the same thing, but along with the desire to generate this dynamically:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql += ' 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT LocationID, Tool = ''' + name + '''
    FROM dbo.ToolsSelected WHERE ' + name + ' = 1'
  FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ToolsSelected')
  AND name LIKE 'Tool[0-9]%';

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT LocID = LocationID, Tool
    FROM
    (' + STUFF(@sql, 1, 17, '') + '
    ) AS x ORDER BY LocID, Tool;';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

---

****BUT****

Storing these as separate columns is a recipe for disaster. So when you add Tool41, Tool42 etc. you have to change the schema then change all your code that passes the column names and 1/0 via parameters etc. Why not represent these as simple numbers, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.LocationTools
(
  LocID  NVARCHAR(40),
  ToolID INT
);
```

So in the above case you would store:

```
LocID  Tool
-----  ----
AZ     2
AZ     3
NY     1
NY     3
NY     4
```

Now when you pass in the checkboxes they've selected, presumably from the front end you are receiving two values, such as:

```
LocID: "NY"
Tools: "Tool1, Tool5, Tool26"
```

If that's about right, then you can populate the table when a user creates or changes their choice, first using a split function to break up the comma-separated list dictated by the checkboxes:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitTools
(
  @ToolList NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT ToolID = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, 
          '<i>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@List, ',', '</i><i>'), 'Tool', '') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

(You forgot to tell us which version of SQL Server you are using - if 2008 or above you could use a table-valued parameter as an alternative to a split function.)

Then a procedure to handle it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateLocationTools
  @LocID NVARCHAR(40),
  @Tools NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- in case they had previously selected tools
  -- that are no longer selected, clear first:

  DELETE dbo.LocationTools WHERE LocID = @LocID;

  INSERT dbo.LocationTools(LocID, ToolID)
    SELECT @LocID, ToolID
    FROM dbo.SplitTools(@Tools);
END
GO
```

Now you can add new tool #s without changing schema or code, since your list of checkboxes could also be generated from your data - assuming you have a `dbo.Tools` table or want to add one. This table could also be used for data integrity purposes (you could put a foreign key on `dbo.LocationTools.ToolID`).

And you can generate your desired query very simply:

```
SELECT LocID, Tool = 'Tool' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ToolID)
  FROM dbo.LocationTools
  ORDER BY LocID, ToolID;
```

No redundant data, no wide tables with unmanageable columns, and a proper index can even help you search for, say, all locations using Tool3 efficiently...

Comment: Thank you, but there are actually 40 columns (tools) involved I was looking for a dynamic means of deternming the column names.

Comment: Maybe you should consider a redesign in the first place. Why are you storing this data across 40 columns? Especially if that's not the way you want to *use* the data?

Comment: I open to any suggestion of a better implementation.  The intent was to have a simple checkbox for the user to select from then pull the details for backend use.

Comment: Thank you.  I will implement this and let you know.